# "uninitialized constant Google::APIClient" when calling Google::APIClient.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-calendar-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm [following one](http://landonmarder.com/posts/2014/06/04/google-cal-rails/) of [many](http://warolv.net/blog/2013/11/16/working-with-google-calendar-v3/) guides how to use Google Calendar API in Rails.

What I don't understand is why the initialization `client = Google::APIClient.new` isn't recognized?

When running that command I receive the error "uninitialized constant Google::APIClient".

I have the following in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'google-api-client', require: 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
```

Comment: try `::Google::APIClient.new`

Comment: or if you sure, it is installed, run `spring stop` and see what you get with your current code.

Comment: hm no. unfortunately none of those suggestion do any difference.

Comment: Ok, please remove `require: 'google/apis/calendar_v3'` and try again..

Comment: and also looks like new gem changed the API https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/d2e51b4e7d4cb5a18cb08b2aed9c0d8ffff14b22/MIGRATING.md#discovery

Comment: same is true here -> https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/d2e51b4e7d4cb5a18cb08b2aed9c0d8ffff14b22/samples/web/app.rb#L94 .. Well so it means, you are using latest gem with old api.. check that ..

Comment: i feel so embarrassed that you have to do all that ground work googling for the obvious. i've seen the syntax of the new api but thought (thanks to pages like this one https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby) that the one i provided would still be functioning. but well, you're right, the new syntax seem to work. thank you arup!

Comment: Cool man! Keep coding.. I am coding in StackOverflow questions .. :p